# How to work with a Pandas Dataframe in a class

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class

I have a dataframe and I want to work with it in a class.
For example, I need a copy of the dataframe and do this grouping:

```
df1 = df[x].groupby(df['date'].dt.date).last()
```

How can I implement it in a class so that I can call it with a function/method?

Desired Output: df1 will be created with the operation in a method()

Comment: I don't see any class or any explanation of what your desired class is supposed to do. You just posted a seemingly random `pandas` operation. Please try to describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: @timgeb better?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution by myself:

```
class mydfclass:

    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def operate(self, new):
        self.new = df.operation...
        return self.new 
        
df1 = mydfclass(df)
df1.operate(df1)
```